How to find duplicates in a text file in python and create a new text file with out them
I am trying to remove duplicates from text files to make a current process more efficient
Example input:
1  1

1   1

2   1

3   1

4   1

Example Output:
1  1

2   1

3   1

4   1

my issue is when the spacing between my numbers is different it will add it to my new text file.
with open('test1.txt') as f:
    with open('test3.txt', 'w') as output:
        seen = list()
        for line in f:
            line_lower = line.strip()
            res = []
            temp = ''
            flag = 1
            for ele in line_lower:
                if ele == ' ' and flag:
                    res.append(temp)
                    temp = ''
                    flag = 0
                else :
                    temp += ele
            res.append(temp)
            print(str(res))
            print((line_lower[0]))
            
            if str(res[0]) in seen:
                print("0")
            else:
                #print(line_lower)
                seen.insert(-1,line_lower)
                output.write(str(line_lower))
                output.write('\n')
                print(str(seen))
output.close()

so far this is white ive been trying, but cant seem to fix my issue

Rather than hard coding, you may want to use regular expressions (regex) check out the python library documentation for regex and probably the most useful site imo for learning about/ using regular expressions: regex101

the 'example output' is not truly representative the input as the 'duplicate'  (line 2) '1   1' differs from line 1 '1  1' , now if that's purely your lack of attention to detail and they are the same, fine, but until you clarify that there are no duplicates in the example input. if you are on a *nix platform try sort -u inputfile and see the output.

I think the major issue of the code is how newlines are handled. You can try:
import re

duplicates = set()
write_next_newline = False

with open("input.txt", "r") as f_in, open("output.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        if not line.strip():
            if write_next_newline:
                f_out.write(line)
            continue

        tpl = tuple(re.findall(r"\d+", line))
        if tpl not in duplicates:
            f_out.write(line)
            duplicates.add(tpl)
            write_next_newline = True
        else:
            write_next_newline = False

output.txt will contain after running this script:
1  1

2   1

3   1

4   1


You can just use str.split to split each line into the numbers it contains. Keep track of them all in a dictionary. After reading the entire file, loop over the dictionary and write all the lines to your output file.
seen_lines = {}
with open('test1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        numbers = tuple(line.strip().split()) # e.g. ('1', '1')
        seen_lines[numbers] = line

with open('output.txt', 'w') as wf:
    for line in seen_lines.values():
        wf.write(line)


The strip() doesn't do anything useful, better remove it.

Could also do seen_lines[*line.split()] = line and later wf.writelines(seen_lines.values()).

@KellyBundy Re strip(): I think it does: The last line could end without a \n but carry the same numbers as a line before, that ends with a \n? But I'd rather use a set seen_lines to check for duplicates (instead of dictionary) and would write directly to the new file.

@Timus It doesn't. The .split() discards leading/trailing whitespace anyway.

@KellyBundy Yep.
